# How to produce a better visualization of data in terms of stacked bar plot in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I ran a program with different threads in two configurations `a` and `b`. I breakdown its timings into `btime`, `stime`, and `vtime`. Please see below for the data. I need to draw stacked plot as you can see below. However, I face difficulty in representing both the number of threads and configs as x-axis labels in R. Could some one help to produce a better representation of this data in terms of stacked plots in R please. Please see the figure and the R code I am using below.

Data:

```
config threads  btime   stime   vtime
a   2   0.08    0.32   0.09
b   2   0.32    0.19   0.16
a   4   3.72 2841.13   0.22
b   4   18.21 2865.79   5.12
a   8   5.45 2824.46   4.77
b   8   23.27 2790.14  11.89
a   16  57.63 3302.55  94.25
b   16  62.41 4041.19  82.56
a   32  119.08 3705.62 210.14
b   32  183.01 4411.14 234.17
a   64  211.51 2823.69 270.38
b   64  364.38 4091.97 387.83
```

R code

```
> barplot(t(data1[c(3:5)]), ylab="Time(seconds)", sp=c(0.1, 0.2, 1.0, 0.2, 1.0, 0.2, 1.0, 0.2, 1.0, 0.2, 1.0, 0.2),col=c("white","gray20","gray60"))
> legend("topleft",legend=c("btime","stime","vtime"), bty="n",cex=1.5 , horiz=T, adj=0.2, fill=c("white","gray20","gray60"))
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you making the plot?  What information are you trying to express more clearly?  There are lots of different things you could do depending on what story you want to tell.

Comment: Aaron: I need to plot the data in terms of a stacked plot as shown above. However, I am having hard-time to represent both configs (column a) and no.of threads (column b) along with X-axis. It would be great help if you give an idea to represent these on the above plot. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ggplot and lattice are very helpful here, however it is useful to think of the data in a different manner: you will want to represent it as something like

```
config threads time_type time_value
[...]  [...]    vtime     0.03
```

melt from reshape accomplishes this (see tutorial http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html)

Then, you can do a plot of something like...
`qplot(config, time_value, data=data, group=time_type, fill=time_type, geom="barplot", facets= .~threads)`

(tutorial @ http://www.r-bloggers.com/basic-introduction-to-ggplot2/)